# What does "int *a = (int[2]){0, 2};" exactly do?

Tags: c

I was very surprised when I saw this notation. What does it do and what kind of C notion is it?

Comment: It fails to compile with VC++ when compiling in C mode. What compiler have you tried?

Comment: It works on GCC, so maybe it is not in the C standard?

Comment: I'm going to guess you are right - that this is yet another GCC extension.  Not sure what you gain with it though.

Comment: @AraK: I think C mode in VC++ is a bit poor.

Comment: VC++, when compiling C code, only supports C89 -- not C99, which is where this feature is defined.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a compound literal as defined in section 6.5.2.5 of the C99 standard.

It's not part of the C++ language, so it's not surprising that C++ compilers don't compile it. (or Java or Ada compilers for that matter)

*The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
the enclosing block.*

So no, it won't destroy the stack. The compiler allocates storage for the object.

Parenthesis are put around the type and it is then followed by an initializer list - it's not a cast, as a bare initialiser list has no meaning in C99 syntax; instead, it is a postfix operator applied to a type which yields an object of the given type. You are not creating `{ 0, 3 }` and casting it to an array, you're initialising an `int[2]` with the values 0 and 3.

---

As to why it's used, I can't see a good reason for it in your single line, although it might be that a could be reassigned to point at some other array, and so it's a shorter way of doing the first two lines of:

```
int default_a[] = { 0, 2 };
int *a = default_a;

if (some_test) a = get_another_array();
```

I've found it useful for passing temporary unions to functions

```
// fills an array of unions with a value
kin_array_fill ( array, ( kin_variant_t ) { .ref = value } )
```

Comment: Great explanation!
Good example with the union, it is quite of a short way to initialize and pass a pointer to a function. It seems to look like anonymous arrays. Shame it is not implemented in C++

Comment: I just looked up for anonymous array in C++ and it seems that something a bit similar is going to be implemented in C++0x: std::initializer_list<>, where, for our example, you can specify std::initializer_list<int> as an argument in the function prototype and give an initializer list such as {0, 2} to the function.

Answer (score 6):

This is a c99 construct, called a *compound literal*.

From the May 2005 committee draft section 6.5.2.5:

> A postfix expression that consists of
> a parenthesized type name followed by
> a brace- enclosed list of initializers
> is a compound literal. It provides an
> unnamed object whose value is given by
> the initializer list.
>
> ...
>
> EXAMPLE 1 The file scope definition

```
int *p = (int []){2, 4};
```

> initializes p
> to point to the first element of an
> array of two ints, the first having
> the value two and the second, four.
> The expressions in this compound
> literal are required to be constant.
> The unnamed object has static storage
> duration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Allocates, on the stack, space for [an array of] two `int`s.
2. Populates [the array of] the two `int`s with the values `0` and `2`, respectively.
3. Declares a local variable of type `int*` and assigns to that variable the address of [the array of] the two `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

(int[2]) tells the compiler that the following expression should be casted to int[2]. This is required since {0, 2} can be casted to different types, like long[2]. Cast occurs at compile time - not runtime.

The entire expression creates an array in memory and sets a to point to this array.

Answer (score -2):

- `{0, 2}` is the notation for an array consisting of 0 and 2.
- `(int[2])` <s>casts it to an array (don't know why)</s>.
- `int * a =` assigns it to the int pointer a.

Comment: Without the cast, the compiler sees it as an attempt to assign multiple values to a scalar variable.